# Ejercicio de función en MySQL, no he podido resolverlo

Tags: mysql, funciones

El problema que intento resolver es el siguiente:

> Cuente el número de estudiantes cuya edad sea mayor a 22.

Mi código hasta el momento:

```
CREATE FUNCTION mayor22() returns int
BEGIN
DECLARE cantidad int;
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cantidad 
FROM estudiante
RETURN cantidad
end;
```

---

El problema es el siguiente: Tengo una tabla estudiante con los siguientes campos:

- doc_est int(30)
- nom_est varchar(30)
- ape_est varchar (30)
- edad_est int(11)

Lo que nos piden es lo siguiente:

Crear una función que cuente el número de estudiantes cuya edad sea mayor a 22.
lo que realice es lo siguiente pero me arroja los errores, no se si sea delimitador o que pueda ser.

```
delimiter //

CREATE FUNCTION mayor22() RETURNS int BEGIN DECLARE cantidad int; SELECT COUNT(edad_est) INTO cantidad FROM estudiante; RETURN cantidad; END

// delimiter
```

Segun el workbench me da error en el row 1 en delimiter y en el último row también delimiter.

Comment: te recomiendo cambiar el titulo de tu pregunta, ya que no especifica cual es tu inquietud, o error, o lo que deseas hacer.

Comment: añade la estructura de la tabla

Comment: Camilo, Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cuando edites una pregunta, pulza sobre el enlace "editar" o pulza aquí: [edit]

Answer (score 1):

Intenta esto:

```
DELIMITER @@
CREATE FUNCTION contar () RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM estudiantes WHERE edad > 22);
END@@
```

**Edit**
Bueno, de acuerdo a lo que el autor pone, la solución sería la siguiente:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION mayor22() RETURNS INT 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE cantidad INT; 
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cantidad FROM estudiante WHERE edad_est > 22; 
    RETURN cantidad; 
END//
```

Comment: podrías explicar tu respuesta para explicar porqué esto resuelve el problema

Comment: pues, no conozco la estructura de la tabla por lo que infiero que se tiene una columna edad, en la consulta original no se filtra la edad (where ...) y eso es lo que lo resuelve... supongo, a menos que el autor de la pregunta tenga otro comentario, además de que la sintáxis de la creación de la función no es correcta

Answer (score 0):

De la siguiente manera te devuelve la cantidad:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'CANTIDAD' FROM 
(SELECT * FROM estudiante WHERE edad_est > 22) T
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno no es que yo sepa mucho del tema, pero diría que es de la siguiente forma:

delimiter // 
CREATE FUNCTION mayor22 () RETURNS INT   #EL NOMBRE DE LA FUNCIÓN 
BEGIN
DECLARE  CANTIDAD INT; #Esta variable es de la función 
SET CANTIDAD =(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ESTUDIANTE WHERE edad_est>22); #DEBES CONSULTAR LA TABLA DONDE NECESITAS SACAR LA INFORMACIÓN
RETURN CANTIDAD;

//DELIMITER ;

END

Pienso que puede ser de esta forma pues estas consultando la tabla estudiante.

Comment: Dale formato al código colocándolo entre triples acentos graves (```) o con el botón que indica `{}`.